# How to disable 'No Items Found' message in TypeAheadField widget

Tags: android, flutter

I have two questions on how to properly use TypeAheadField widget.

My TypeAheadField is created in the following way:

```
TypeAheadField<PostListOfProducts?>(
            hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: false,
            minCharsForSuggestions: 2,
            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              controller: _typeAheadController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: 'Wyszukaj produkt',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.blue),
              ),
            ),
            suggestionsCallback: ApiDataSingleton.instance.productSuggestions,
            itemBuilder: (context, PostListOfProducts? suggestion) {
              final post = suggestion!;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(post.nazwa!),
              );
            },
            noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) {
              return const SizedBox(height: 40, child: Center(child: Text('Brak produktów', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))));
              },
            onSuggestionSelected: (PostListOfProducts? suggestion) {
              final post = suggestion!;
              setState(() {
                _name = post.nazwa.toString();
                _typeAheadController.text = post.nazwa.toString();
              });
            },
          )
```

I would like to learn how to disable (not change as done above, but disable at all) 'No Items Found' message and how to get written text value of TypeAheadField widget that does not match any items.

Could you please advise? Thanks.

Comment: just return `Sizedbox()`, without specify any size.  it will display nothing in the screen

Comment: You are right... it works... thanks... Do you know an answer to second question?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question:

- How to disable (not change as done above, but disable at all) 'No Items Found' message

> just return Sizedbox(), without specify any size. it will display
> nothing in the screen

actually its provided to hide:

```
  /// If set to true, nothing will be shown if there are no results.
  /// [noItemsFoundBuilder] will also be ignored.
  ///
  /// Defaults to false.
  final bool hideOnEmpty;
```

so, you just set this props as `true`

---

- How to get written text value of TypeAheadField widget that does not match any items.

> you can get it from the `suggestionsCallback`

example:

```
suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
   print(pattern); /// this will print the latest string that you type
   return BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern);
   //return Future(() => []);
```

the `pattern` is the last `String` that you type in the field.